# PowerShell Not the right characters after uppercase letters

Tags: powershell

I am trying to send this data: "forTEST2_Flash_Drive_1" to a PuTTY console. Once in a while I will get a "@" instead of "2" or "!" instead of "!". I don't think it is releasing the shift key after an upper case.

```bsh
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject WScript.Shell;
$wshell.AppActivate('test') 
sleep 1
$wshell.SendKeys('forTEST2_Flash_Drive_1')
```

Comment: Do not try to automate typing text into PuTTY. The PuTTY suite provides tools for scripting remote commands (specifically `plink.exe`). Use that.

Comment: I can't use plink.exe in this case, because I need to have visual of PuTTY for some of the things I am doing.